# CSS3 flip effect: z-index gets screwed up after 3D-transform

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a flip card effect following [this tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip). Basically, it puts two panes in a container and applies a `transform: rotateY(180deg)` to make one of the pages facing the back. The flip effect is achieved by transform the container 180deg. This is the basic html:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <!-- back content -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The flip effects woks fine, but in safari, when I try to catch any touch/click event on the back pane, it simply does not fire after some flips(see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blurrcat/g6M9d/)). The back pane seems to sit on top of the front pane.

This [blog](http://daneden.me/2012/04/css-transforms-and-z-index/) points out that z-index gets screwed up when you apply a transform. How can I fix this or is there any way to avoid using z-index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I make a different approach with you example. Here's the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wandarkaf/g6M9d/24/)

All I do was to create click's events that flips or exchange the z-index along with the transition effect (this function, of course, can be optimized):

```
      var rotation = 180;
```

```
  $(".front").click(function () {
   $("div.flipper").css("transform", "rotateY(" + rotation + "deg)");
   rotation += 180; // flip the card only one way
   $(".front").css("z-index","1");
   $(".back").css("z-index","2");
  });


  $(".back").click(function () {
    $("div.flipper").css("transform", "rotateY(" + rotation + "deg)");
    rotation += 180; // flip the card only one way
    $(".back").css("z-index","1");
    $(".front").css("z-index","2");
  });
```

​

Hope this helps.